# disable weblogic basic authentication without changing config.xml

Tags: xml, authentication, weblogic-10.x

I have developed an app which uses jersey RESTful web services. After entering the login credentials of the app, weblogic pops up and asks for authentication. How do I disable basic authentication of weblogic (by changing `config.xml`) i.e. without using:

```
<enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>false</enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>
```

Comment: i have seen similar post but no answers please help

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using a WLST script.
Here is an example:

```
connect('weblogic_user','weblogic_password','t3://localhost:80')
cd('SecurityConfiguration/Your_WL_Domain_Name')
edit()
startEdit()
set('EnforceValidBasicAuthCredentials','false')
save()
activate()
exit()
```